# Serial received data not recognised

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi, pic

I am connecting PIC with Raspberry PI through a serial port. My max485 transmit and receive enable pin is controlled by gpio pin. My received data is printed successfully. But it is not performing the desired function.

```
while True:
   GPIO.output(repin, False)
   port.flushInput()
   time.sleep(.oo5)
   port.write(bytes(address))
   time.sleep(.01)
   GPIO.output(repin, Ture)
   port.flushInput()
   data=port.readline()
   if data:
      address=address+1
      if data == "ok" :
         print "reached"
      print data
   if not data:
      print "no data"
```

when I am receiving OK. It prints "ok" but it didn't print "reached". And when data is not received it is printing a blank value instead of "no data".

Comment: Perhaps it's possible that the string you receive conatins a terminating CR, LF or NULL. Try specifically comparing just the first two characters.

Comment: Your code starts with "while Ture". I suppose it should be "while True"?

Comment: when data=port.read(2) is used then it works fine. but i need to use readline() . my data may be 2 or 3 byte long.@ Roger Rowland

Comment: yes you r right.it's just a silly mistake not my actual problem@S.L. Barth

Comment: what you get with print type(data), len(data) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code. If you write PIC program correctly then the problem is coming from the proper termination resistors of max485.connect twisted pair cable ground with proper resistance.

Comment: i will inform you after changing the resistors@Akash Nil

Comment: By adding A & B to ground and connecting 4.7k serial to them the problem is solved.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `UART_Write` method at `PIC` micro-controller side. Are you sending `\r` or `\n` extra along with `ok` ? You can clarify that by using debugger at `PIC` and monitoring the `PIC` UART write register in watch window, which is **`TXREG`**